# Segmentation fault: concatenating string

Tags: c

I'm trying to concatenate two chars and get a segmentation error on the line above return.
When I used char instead of char*, the (onechar-a + 'A') worked although I wasn't trying to concatenate.  If I leave this as char instead of char* I get warnings about casting.

```
char *carat;
carat = test_carat(ttyinfo.c_cc[VINTR]);
carat = test_carat(ttyinfo.c_cc[VINTR]);

char * test_carat(char onechar)
{
    if (onechar >= 32 || onechar !=127)
    {
        if (iscntrl(onechar))
        {
            char * returnString =  strcat((char*)'^',  (char*)(onechar - 1 + 'A'));
            return returnString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `strcat((char*)'^',` You cannot cast an int literal to a char pointer (and append to it ...) `if (onechar >= 32 || onechar !=127) {
` also looks very wrong.

Comment: Maybe `(char*)'^'` isn't such a good idea. Strings in C are really, really complicated, and you must make sure that you're well at home with pointers and memory allocation before you use C string operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work:

```
   strcat((char*)'^',  (char*)(onechar - 1 + 'A') )
```

You shouldn't cast a character to a char pointer. The effect is that the character value (a value <= 255) will be used as address of the character pointer by `strcat`, this is why your program segfaults.

You can do that:

```
char * test_carat(char onechar)
{
    if (onechar >= 32 || onechar !=127)
    {
        if (iscntrl(onechar))
        {
            char * returnString = (char *)malloc(3);
            returnString[0] = '^';
            returnString[1] = (onechar - 1 + 'A');
            returnString[2] = '\0';
            return returnString;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Also '^' is a character literal - its memory is a byte within the body of the code. So even if you tried to get its memory with & you would be attempting to concatenate another char onto the end of that memory location - overwriting program memory.

You need to dynamically allocate heap memory for returnString or at least declare it as a 3 char array - and pass that as the first parameter of strcat.

Comment: @pivotnig I'm trying to do the concatenation but now I get "passing arg 2 of strcat makes pointer from integer without a cast char * returnString = malloc(3); if (iscntrl(onechar)) { char * newChar =(char*)(onechar - 1 + 'A'); strcat(returnString,'^'); strcat(returnString, newChar ) ; return returnString; }

Comment: You *can* cast a character constant to `char*`.  But you shouldn't.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that if this example is used, the caller has to remember to call `free()` on the return value.